# Is it reasonable to terminate multi-threaded processing via a queue by means of a special object in the queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am quite experienced in single-threaded Python as well as embarrasingly parallel multi-processing, but this is the first time I attempt processing something with a producer- and a consumer-thread via a shared queue.
The producer thread is going to download data items from URLs and put them in a queue. Simultaneously, a consumer thread is going to process the data items as they arrive on the queue.
Eventually, there will be no more data items to download and the program should terminate. I wish for the consumer thread to be able to distinguish whether it should keep waiting at an empty queue, because more items may be coming in, or it should terminate, because the producer thread is done.
I am considering signaling the latter situation by placing a special object on the queue in the producer thread when there are no more data items to download. When the consumer thread sees this object, it then stops waiting at the queue and terminates.
Is this a sensible approach?

Comment: Yes, it's reasonable.  See this (IMHO) [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60079767/132382) about waking a known number of blocking queue consumers, or this [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30219705/132382) wherein the number of producers, but not consumers, is known _a priori_.

Comment: FYI, A special object that signals a consumer thread to shut down and self-terminate is known in some circles as a _poison pill._